# Dynamically populate column with worksheet name

Tags: excel, vba

I need to populate cells within a specific column with the name of the worksheet.

I have the following code for populating a single cell:

```
Sub Worksheet_Name_Plop()
    Cells.WrapText = False ' Disables WordWrap
    [AG2].Value = ActiveSheet.Name
    Columns("AG").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```

The trouble I'm having is there may be anywhere from one to 10,000+ lines of data per worksheet. Not sure of how to populate just the rows that have data.

There is a header row so it's important that the results start on the second row of each worksheet.

For efficiency: I also need to be able to do this across all worksheets of the same file.

Any assistance greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there one column that will have contiguous data down to the last row, for example column A?

Comment: My apologies, A is fair game!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

10 million rows in 9 seconds:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub setID1()
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Const COL       As String = "AG"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, t As Double, tr As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: t = Timer
    For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

        ws.Range(COL & FIRST_ROW & ":" & COL & lastRow).Value2 = ws.Name
        With ws.Cells(FIRST_ROW, COL)
            .WrapText = False
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
        tr = tr + lastRow - FIRST_ROW + 1
    Next
    Debug.Print "setID1 - Sheets: " & Worksheets.Count & _
                       ", Rows: " & tr & ", Duration: " & Timer - t
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

```
Public Sub setID2()
    Const FIRST_ROW As Long = 2
    Const COL       As String = "AG"
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, t As Double, tr As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False: t = Timer
    For Each ws In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

        With ws.Cells(FIRST_ROW, COL)
            .Value2 = ws.Name
            .WrapText = False
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
        ws.Range(COL & FIRST_ROW & ":" & COL & lastRow).FillDown
        tr = tr + lastRow - FIRST_ROW + 1
    Next
    Debug.Print "setID2 - Sheets: " & Worksheets.Count & _
                       ", Rows: " & tr & ", Duration: " & Timer - t
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Tests:

```
setID1 - Sheets: 10, Rows: 10000000, Duration: 9.08203125
setID1 - Sheets: 10, Rows: 10000000, Duration: 9.064453125
setID1 - Sheets: 10, Rows: 10000000, Duration: 9.0625

setID2 - Sheets: 10, Rows: 10000000, Duration: 8.580078125
setID2 - Sheets: 10, Rows: 10000000, Duration: 8.58203125
setID2 - Sheets: 10, Rows: 10000000, Duration: 8.56640625
```

Comment: Lightning fast indeed! Are the print stats comment line supposed to updated when ran? Also (didn't see this until tested), can word wrap be disabled for the results?

Comment: I updated it to include `.WrapText = False` and also a slightly faster alternative (`.FillDown`). The print stats line will update when executed but you'll have to open the Immediate Window: in VBA editor - View -> Immediate Window (`Ctrl+G`)

Comment: Increased by .1 second. Flagged =P

Comment: Finally getting to reading the code XD HUH. So `with` is slower eh. Good to know ^_^

Comment: @findwindow - no, `with` is faster, but in the second option the `.FillDown` is faster (I'll have to test this: both solutions using `with`, the 1st changed to use `.Value2 = `, and 1 million records in each sheet)

Comment: 9 seconds for 10 million rows. Now you're just bragging. Flagged =P

Answer (score 0):

Loop though the rows and check a column for data, then write the name in that row if it exists.

```
Sub Worksheet_Name_Plop()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iIndex As Integer

    For iIndex = 1 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.count

        Set ws = Worksheets(iIndex)
        ws.Activate

        'Start at row 2
        lRow = 2

        'Loop through the rows in the worksheet
        Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

            'Check if some column has data
            If ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then
                 'Write the worksheet name to column AG of that row
                 ws.Range("AG" & lRow).Value = ws.Name
            End if

            'Increment you counter
            lRow = lRow + 1
            ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
        Loop

       Columns("AG").Select
       Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Next iIndex    

End Sub
```

Comment: This works, can watch it loop through the worksheets!

Comment: Yeah, there are fast ways to do things but if it's a one time thing or something like that, I go with a simple loop. Sometimes it's easier to see what is going on and feel comfortable that it's working.